# Some text is hiding at the end in my validation screen. How cam I fix this in react-native

Tags: react-native, stylesheet

My Validation text is hidden at the end. Can anyone suggest any solution for this?

In the message part there is more than 4 validation message. Here if it fails and shows only one message it hides at the end.

```
validation.messages = {
    1. Email validation message
    2. Username validation and so on
}

    <View style = {{flex: 1,marginTop: '2.3%', flexWrap: 'nowrap', justifyContent:'center'}}>
    {
     validation.messages.map((msg) => { return <Text style = {{textAlign:'left',textWrap:'rap',  fontSize:12, color: '#AC1229', marginBottom: '7%', }}> {msg} </Text>
       })
     }
   </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once ,

```
validation.messages = [
       '1. Email validation message',
       '2. Username validation and so on'

    ]


    <View style = {{flex: 1,marginTop: '2.3%', flexWrap: 'nowrap', justifyContent:'center'}}>
        {
         validation.messages.map((msg) => { return <Text style = {{textAlign:'left',textWrap:'wrap',  fontSize:12, color: '#AC1229', marginBottom: '7%', }}> {msg} </Text>
           })
         }
       </View>
```

Check the expo link too , [expo link](https://snack.expo.io/rJaVvV1kU)

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts